# How to scroll specific element in the div?

Tags: angular, ionic3

I want to scroll the content which is selected by user in horizontal way using id of the div

**This is html code:**

```
<ion-scroll #scroll scrollX="true" style="height:85px; border-bottom: 2px solid #a01e1e;">
<div class="scroll-item">
<ion-col col-10 *ngFor="let date1 of dateJson.data(click)="selectDate1(date1.apt_id, date1.full_date)">
<div class="div_date" *ngIf="appoint_date != date1.full_date" >
                    <span> {{date1.date}} {{date1.day}} </span>
                    <span> {{date1.month}} </span>
                </div>
                <div class="div_date_select" *ngIf="appoint_date == date1.full_date" id="date1" #date >
                    <span id="date1"> {{date1.date}} {{date1.day}} </span>
                    <span id="date1" > {{date1.month}} </span>
                </div>
            </ion-col>
        </div>
    </ion-scroll>
```

**This is ts file and I can't find the id of element:**

```
this.scrollTo();
scrollTo() {
var m = document.getElementById('date1');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to acheive the same but I would recommend using `scrollToPosition` under `ViewportScroller` If you are using Angular version > 6.

It accepts position coordinates where to scroll like this -

```
getScrollPosition(): [number, number]
```

- https://angular.io/api/common/ViewportScroller#getscrollposition

<kbd>[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-scroller)</kbd>

Comment: i don't get the exact position of element .

Comment: Can you create stackblizte for the same?